# Uploading a file with FTP in Windows 10. Getting a Timeout error

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting a timeout error at this line of code in the sample:

```
Dim _Stream As System.IO.Stream = _WebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

My PC was recently switched over to Windows 10. The previous operating system was Windows 7.
The app was developed under Windows 7. The entire class is below.
I need to know the possible sources of the timeout. The app worked just fine under Windows 7. When my PC was switched to Windows 10, the app failed.

```
Public Class ftpUpload

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Methods to upload file to FTP Server
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="_FileName">local source file name</param>
    ''' <param name="_UploadPath">Upload FTP path including Host name. DON'T FORGET TO INCLUDE THE FILE NAME OF THE TARGET FILE!!  
    ''' The one for Carfax is "ftp://ftp.carfax.com/" plus the file name (yyyymmdd-yyyymmdd.xml) </param>
    ''' <param name="_FTPUser">FTP login username</param>
    ''' <param name="_FTPPass">FTP login password</param>

    Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal _FileName As String,
                          ByVal _UploadPath As String,
                          ByVal _FTPUser As String,
                          ByVal _FTPPass As String)

        ' get the file information
        Dim _FileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName)

        ' Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
        'Dim _FtpWebRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(_UploadPath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        Dim _WebRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(New Uri(_UploadPath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

        ' Provide the WebPermission Credintials
        _WebRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)

        ' By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
        ' after a command is executed.
        _WebRequest.KeepAlive = False

        _WebRequest.UsePassive = False

        ' set timeout for 30 seconds (30 * 1000)
        _WebRequest.Timeout = 30000

        ' Specify the command to be executed.
        _WebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        ' Specify the data transfer type.
        _WebRequest.UseBinary = True

        ' Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
        _WebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length

        ' The buffer size is set to 2kb
        Dim buffLength As Integer = 2048
        Dim buff(buffLength - 1) As Byte

        ' Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
        Dim _FileStream As System.IO.FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead()

        Try
            ' Stream to which the file to be upload is written
            Dim _Stream As System.IO.Stream = _WebRequest.GetRequestStream()

            ' Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
            Dim contentLen As Integer = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)

            ' Till Stream content ends
            Do While contentLen <> 0
                ' Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
                _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen)
                contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
            Loop

            ' Close the file stream and the Request Stream
            _Stream.Close()
            _Stream.Dispose()
            _FileStream.Close()
            _FileStream.Dispose()
            GC.Collect()
        Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This code supposes `.UsePassive = True`. The Stream Read/Write proc is questionable.

Comment: There's no reason to set .KeepAlive = False. It also means close the connection (or it might, different factors involved). What about `_WebRequest.EnableSsl = True`? Are you sure it's not required? The defaul is False.

Comment: Jimi.  I'll try changing some properties according to your suggestions.  I didn't write this code originally, so I'm not sure what everything in it does, and I'm hesitant to just change something without supporting opinion.  Thanks.

Comment: `KeepAlive = True` is the default value because .Net uses connection pool and it manages these connections thorough a ServicePoint class. In a FTP connection, `KeepAlive = False` also means *close the connection*. `.UsePassive = False` means that the FTP Server will not be the only active party: your app need to send commands accordingly, and you're not sending any, which is the standard `.UsePassive = True` behaviour. You don't need to listen to *opinions*, you need to read the Docs about it.

Comment: Well, I set _WebRequest.EnableSsl = True and .KeepAlive = True.  I got the same failed results.   Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, nobody said that your Server requires a SSL connection. If it does (you should know), you also need to add the required `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` and, possibly, the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. Read the Docs about these, too. If the Server requires TLS1.2 (`SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`), you also need .Net Framework 4.5+ (4.5.2).

Comment: But, you have said whether you have set `Passive = True`. Without it, your code, in its current state, isn't going anywhere (unless you're using some sort of *special* server, that resets the Passive state).

Comment: Jimi, thanks.  I set UsePassive = True and everything works.  I don't have the documentation for this (and the person who wrote it is long gone).   I'm so ignorant on this subject I don't even know where to start to look.  They just throw us in the pool and it's just sink or swim.